# Geometry Generator/Transformation rendering in ArcGIS Server like GeoServer and QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, geoserver, arcgis-pro, arcgis-server, qgis-server

[GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/rendering_tx.html) allows geometries to be generated by integrating transformations from WPS into SLD.

[QGIS Server](https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/08/a-guide-to-geometry-generator-symbol-layers/) can also do this from the Desktop configuration with geometry generator symbology.

With ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Pro, based on a polygon table, can I generate points (geoids for example) on a large scale and display polygons on small scales with a single layer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on [ArcGIS Pro support](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-symbolize-polygon-feature-layers-as-points-relat-000030009#:%7E:text=In%20ArcGIS%20Pro%2C%20polygon%20feature,smaller%20scales%20in%20ArcGIS%20Pro.).

Configured with ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0
It's published (compatible) with ArcGIS Server 10.9.1